# Memory address instead of value in cout of class

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, forward-list

I am trying to write own simple forward list implementation. I'd like to access element by cout << list[0]. I wrote the following code but instead of value I got something like x637c00539997. What did I do wrong? 
What else can I improve in my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class myList{
public:

  class myListExceptionEmpty: public exception
  {
  public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
      return "EMPTY";
    }
  };

  void push_back(int valve);
  int getSize();
  bool isEmpty();
  void removeFirst();
  void remove(int x);
  void dump();
  void pop_front();
  struct elem
  {
    std::shared_ptr<elem> next;
    int val;
  };
  class proxy
  {
  public:
    std::shared_ptr<myList::elem>  position;
    proxy(std::shared_ptr<myList::elem> pos)
    {
      position = pos;
    }
  };
  std::shared_ptr<myList::proxy> operator[](int position);

private:
  std::shared_ptr<elem> start;
  std::shared_ptr<elem> getLastElement();
  std::shared_ptr<proxy> current;
  int size = 0;


};

ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, myList::proxy& obj)
{
      os << obj.position->val;
      return os;
}

shared_ptr<myList::proxy> myList::operator[](int position)
{
  std::shared_ptr<elem> p = start;
  for(int i=0;i<position;i++)
  {
    p = p->next;
    if (p == NULL) throw std::out_of_range("out");
  }
  //cout << p->val;
  std::shared_ptr<proxy> tmp(new myList::proxy(p));
  current = tmp;
  return current;
}

std::shared_ptr<myList::elem> myList::getLastElement()
{
    std::shared_ptr<elem> p = start;
    while(p->next != NULL ) p = p->next;
    return p;
}

bool myList::isEmpty()
{
  return size;
}

void myList::dump()
{
  std::shared_ptr<elem> x = start;
  while (x != NULL)
  {
      cout << x->val << endl;
        x = x->next;
  }
}

void myList::push_back(int valve)
{
  std::shared_ptr<elem> p, n(new elem());
  n->next = NULL;
  n->val = valve;
  p = start;
  if(p != NULL)
  {
     while(p->next != NULL ) p = p->next;
     p->next = n;
  }
  else start = n;
  size++;

}

void myList::remove(int x)
{
  if (size == 0) throw myListExceptionEmpty();
  std::shared_ptr<elem> p, prv;
  p = start;
  while(p->next != NULL)
  {
    if (p->val == x)
    {
      prv->next = p->next;
      size--;
    }
    prv = p;
    p = p->next;
  }
}

void myList::pop_front()
{

  if (size == 0) throw myListExceptionEmpty();
  std::shared_ptr<elem> p, prv;
  p = start;
  while(p->next != NULL)
  {
    prv = p;
    p = p->next;
  }
  prv->next = NULL;

}
void myList::removeFirst()
{
  if (size == 0) throw myListExceptionEmpty();
  std::shared_ptr<elem> p;
  p = start;
  cout << start->val << endl;
  if(p!= NULL)
  {
    start = p->next;
  }
  size--;

}

int myList::getSize()
{
  return size;
}

int main()
{
  myList array;
  int size;
  cin >> size;

  char a;
  int tmp;
  for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
    std::cin >> a;
    if (a == 'D')
    {
      try{
      array.removeFirst();
    }
    catch (myList::myListExceptionEmpty &e)
    {
      cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    }
    else if (a == 'A')
    {
        int tmp;
        std::cin >> tmp;
        array.push_back(tmp);
        cout << "elem" << array[0];
    }
    else if (a == 'S') cout /*<< "Size:"*/ << array.getSize() << endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your `operator[]` returns a `shared_ptr<myList::proxy>`, so what did you expect to get printed?

Comment: os << *(obj.position->val); give me error: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the question "what else to improve":

- You're using shared pointers, great! Instead of using `new` use the corresponding routine `make_shared` (see C++ documentation).
- Do not define classes in classes. Let each class have its own header and source file. It increases readability dramatically and even compiling gets faster by splitting all classes into different files (best way: use include guards). This way you can also leave the namespaces like `myList::elem`.
- Use `<cassert>` instead of `<assert.h>`. You're using C++11 anyway, so why the need to use an old C-library?!
- Just an example: Change `void myList::remove(int x)` to `void myList::remove(const int& x)`. Let the compiler know that `x` is a read-only object. Do not call the int-copy constructor here (also at other code lines).

With regard to your 2nd question: your overloaded operator `[]` returns a shared-pointer and not the object this pointer is pointing at. Thus, it will print the address of the pointer.

Comment: Thank you, can you give a any tip how make cout << list[0] working?

Comment: @piotr712 Did you try dereferencing: `cout << *list[0]`?

Comment: What about `cout << *list[0] << endl`? Does this work?

Comment: Why would one prefer the "int copy constructor" over a reference initialization?

Comment: When giving short types to functions it's better to give them by value instead by const reference. Many times it's cheaper to make copy of int rather than creating a reference to it.

Comment: Yes it's working. Thank you. Simple and working solution.

Comment: So in your `cout` statement you want to print `array[0]`. `array[0]` returns an `std::shared_ptr<myList::proxy>` (btw, leave the std:: here, you included the standard-namespace already). So you need on ofstream-operator which takes a shared-pointer of a proxy and returns the corresponding `val`. I cannot find this operator...may this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is program after fix. I used cout << *array[0]; instead of cout << array[0];. Than you for help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
class MyListProxy;
class MyListExceptionEmpty: public exception
{
public:
  virtual const char* what() const throw(){
    return "EMPTY";
  }
};



class MyList{
public:
  void push_back(int valve);
  int getSize() { return size; };
  bool empty() { return size; };
  void removeFirst();
  void remove(const int& x);
  void dump();
  void pop_front();
  void clear() {this->start = NULL; size = 0;}
  struct elem
  {
    shared_ptr<elem> next;
    int val;
  };
  shared_ptr<MyListProxy> operator[](int position);
private:
  shared_ptr<elem> start;
  shared_ptr<MyListProxy> current;
  shared_ptr<elem> getEnd();
  int size = 0;

};

class MyListProxy
{
public:
  shared_ptr<MyList::elem> position;
  MyListProxy(shared_ptr<MyList::elem> pos)
  {
    position = pos;
  }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, MyListProxy& obj)
{
  os << obj.position->val;
  return os;
}

shared_ptr<MyListProxy> MyList::operator[](int position)
{
  if (start == NULL) throw out_of_range("out");
  shared_ptr<elem> p = start;
  for(int i=0;i<position;i++){
    p = p->next;
    if (p == NULL) throw out_of_range("out");
  }
  return make_shared <MyListProxy>(p);
}

shared_ptr<MyList::elem> MyList::getEnd()
{
  if (start == NULL) return start;
   shared_ptr<elem> p = start;
   while(p->next != NULL ) p = p->next;
   return p->next;
}

void MyList::dump()
{
  shared_ptr<elem> x = start;
  while (x != NULL)
  {
    cout << x->val << endl;
    x = x->next;
  }
}

void MyList::push_back(int valve)
{
  shared_ptr<elem> p;
  auto last = this->getEnd();
  auto a =  make_shared<elem>();
  last = a;
  last->val = valve;
  size++;

}

void MyList::remove(const int& x)
{
  if (size == 0) throw MyListExceptionEmpty();
  shared_ptr<elem> p, prv;
  p = start;
  while(p->next != NULL)
  {
    if (p->val == x)
    {
      prv->next = p->next;
      size--;
    }
    prv = p;
    p = p->next;
  }
}

void MyList::pop_front()
{

  if (size == 0) throw MyListExceptionEmpty();
  start = start->next;
}


int main()
{
  MyList array;
  int size;
  cin >> size;

  char a;
  int tmp;
  for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
    cin >> a;
    if (a == 'D')
    {
      try{
        cout << *array[0];
        array.pop_front();
      }
      catch (MyListExceptionEmpty &e)
      {
        cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
      }
      catch (out_of_range &e)
      {
        cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
      }
    }
    else if (a == 'A')
    {
      int tmp;
      cin >> tmp;
      array.push_back(tmp);
    }
    else if (a == 'S') cout /*<< "Size:"*/ << array.getSize() << endl;
    cout << "SIZE::" << array.getSize() << endl;
  }

}
```